# Python threading memory error when running for some time

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, memory

I am having a new error arise in one of my scripts that was not happening before. I'm having threads die often and easily now and I have no idea what's causing it. I used to be able to run this for weeks without any problems but I think this may be leaking memory...?? I'm afraid this may harm the computer local that is running the script as well.

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inne
r
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "innvictus02.py", line 732, in Task
    resp = sess.get(product_url, proxies=proxy, timeout=15)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 5
43, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 5
30, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 6
65, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 6
65, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 2
37, in resolve_redirects
    resp = self.send(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 6
83, in send
    r.content
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 829
, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
MemoryError
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inne
r
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "innvictus02.py", line 750, in Task
    soup = bs(resp.text, 'html.parser')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 862
, in text
    content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace')
MemoryError
```